# Is the theory of asymptotic bounds finitely axiomatizable?

Tags: lo.logic, asymptotics

Let $F$ be the set of functions over real numbers.
Consider the structure $M = \langle F, <, \leq, =, \geq, > \rangle$ where the $<, \leq, =, \geq, >$ are defined as asymptotic notions $o$, $O$, $\Theta$, $\Omega$, $\omega$. For example, for $f,g\in F$, $f\leq g$ iff $f \in O(g)$.

Consider the first-order theory of this structure $T = Th(M)$.

Questions:

> Is $T$ finitely axiomatizable?
>
> Does $T$ have quantifier elimination property?
>
> Is $T$ a decidable theory?

Is there a references discussing logical and model theoretic properties of this theory (statements similar to those above)?

Comment: An optimistic guess: might this just be the theory of distributive lattices with zero?

Comment: @Colin, as a theory of a structure the theory needs to be complete, I don't think the theory of distributed lattices with zero is a complete theory.

Comment: Nice question! Could you give examples of interesting theorems that could be expressed in this theory? Do you know if there are any open questions?

Comment: @Vijay, I was looking at the standard properties of asymptotic notations like $f \leq g \land g  \leq h \rightarrow f \leq h$, $\exists f,g,h \ (f \leq g \land f \neq g \land f \not < g)$, $\forall f,g \ \exists h \ [f,g \leq h \land \forall h' \ (f,g \leq h' \rightarrow h \leq h')]$.

Comment: It would be much more interesting if we would through in some other constants and operations like $0:x \mapsto 0$, $1:x \mapsto 1$, $id: x \mapsto x$, $+$, $\cdot$, $o$ (composition), etc. so that we can express more interesting statements but the theory becomes too strong as soon as we have addition and multiplication.

Comment: Would it help to consider a countable model instead, something like finite tuples of natural numbers?

Comment: @András, I don't know if that would be a model of this theory. Obviously there is a countable model, however I haven't thought about how a countable model would look like. That might be a good way to look at the question, if there is a simple countable model then we can consider the theory of that model in place of functions over reals.

Comment: Is the zero function little-o of itself? ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ If no and quantifier elimination is not allowed to introduce additional variables, then the answer to ​ "Does $T$ have quantifier elimination property?" ​ is no for trivial reasons: ​ ​ ​ $(\forall g)(\hspace{.04 in}f\leq g)$ ​ has exactly one _free_ variable and is true if and only if f is eventually-always zero, but formulas with only one variable don't actually depend on that variable. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: (The answer to my previous comment's starting question is determined by $\hspace{1.71 in}$ whether your definition of little-o uses < or ≤.) ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer, F is all real function, so there is no function that is dominated by all functions, so the formula you have is equivalent to always false formula. But what if we restricted F to just the positive ones? I think in that case it would be fair to at least have constant functions and then the formula would be equivalent to $f \leq 0$.

Comment: Let z be the zero function. ​ ​ ​ For all real functions g, 0 and 1 are real numbers such that for all $\hspace{.68 in}$ real numbers x, if ​ 0 ≤ x ​ then ​ z(x) = 0 ≤ 1$\cdot$|g(x)| . ​ ​ ​ Thus z is dominated by all real functions. $\hspace{.83 in}$